# Embedded SQL database with encryption?

Tags: sql, .net, database, embedded-database

I'm looking for a SQL database engine that I can distribute with a C# Winforms application. The requirements are:

> 1. Will store about 1GB of text (measured before any compression).
> 2. Database must be encrypted, the encryption key will be supplied by the application at runtime.
> 3. Compression (prior to encryption) would be nice, so that corrupt databases can be replaced remotely over a low-bandwidth network
>      connection.
> 4. Reliability, replacing a corrupt database can involve an expensive site visit.
> 5. Low licencing costs and support costs.
> 6. Users will only access the data via the application, so no fancy UI required.

Options I've considered:

> 1. Sybase SQL Anywhere - OK, but not "free".
> 2. MS SQL Server Express - no whole-database encryption!
> 3. SQLite - encryption requires a licence payment?
> 4. VistaDB - not "free".

What other products fit the bill?

Answer (score 1):

Get the Visual Studio "**SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox**" Extension. Using this:

**Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact** from Nuget will create encrypted databases provided you manually run the command

```
Create Database "something.sdf" databasepassword 'somepassword'
```

in the extension's query window.

**System.Data.SQLite.Core** from Nuget will use encrypted databases provided you use the above extension to create the database and key in a password at database create time.